# Best query to pick row based on IP address and DateStamp

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Supposed I have `Table1` that have `account_id`, `ip_address` and `created_date` columns but on the other table, `Table2` has only `ip_address` and `created_date` columns. `Table2` doesn't have an `account_id` that I can use to join in table1. For some reason from the management, I still need to assume or pick `accounts_id`s from `Table1` to fill it in `Table2`.

What will be the best way to pick accounts_ids from `Table1`?
I tried the query below but it seems that there are accounts from Table1 which is obviously doesn't belong to Table2 due to created_date comparison. I wonder if there are ways to do this such as comparing `YEAR(create_date)` or etc?

```
SELECT t2.ip_address, t2.created_date, t1.account_id 
FROM Table2 t2 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT account_id, ip_address, MAX(created_date) created_date
            FROM Table1 t1
            GROUP BY account_id, ip_address  
           ) t1 
on t2.ip_address = t1.ip_address
```

*EDIT:* Note that I just want to pick the closest date as possible since IP address and dates are not unique on `Table1`.

Comment: why are you using MAX(created_date)? same ip = same account?

Comment: Hi @McNets, I've tried MIN(create_date) but It seems that MAX(created_date) would be the closest same ip = same account pick.

Comment: is there more than one record by ip_address on Table1?

Comment: Unfortunately there is.

Comment: Could you add a minimum example of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this sample data cover your current issue.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1(account int, ip_address varchar(15), created_date date);
> INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES
> (1, '10.0.0.1', '20170101'),
> (1, '10.0.0.1', '20170201'),
> (1, '10.0.0.1', '20170301'),
> (2, '10.0.0.2', '20170201'),
> (3, '10.0.0.3', '20170201');
>
> CREATE TABLE Table2(ip_address varchar(15), created_date date);
> INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES
> ('10.0.0.1', '20170201'),
> ('10.0.0.2', '20170201'),
> ('10.0.0.3', '20170201');
> ```

This solution assumes that, at least, there is a `created_date` on your `Table1` >= of the `created_date` on `Tabel2`

> ```
> SELECT (SELECT TOP (1) account
>         FROM     Table1 t1
>         WHERE    t1.ip_address = t2.ip_address
>         AND      t1.created_date >= t2.created_date
>         ORDER BY t1.ip_address, t1.created_date desc) account,
>        t2.ip_address, 
>        t2.created_date
> FROM   Table2 t2
> ```
>
> ```
> account | ip_address | created_date       
> ------: | :--------- | :------------------
>       1 | 10.0.0.1   | 01/02/2017 00:00:00
>       2 | 10.0.0.2   | 01/02/2017 00:00:00
>       3 | 10.0.0.3   | 01/02/2017 00:00:00
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=764efe772571f6f79783baf4673b99b1)*

If there is no an exact date, you can build a list of periods:

> ```
> WITH ipList as
> (
>     SELECT account, ip_address, created_date, 
>            COALESCE(LEAD(created_date) OVER (PARTITION BY account, ip_address ORDER BY created_date), created_date) next_date
>     FROM   Table1
> )
> select * from iplist;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> account | ip_address | created_date        | next_date          
> ------: | :--------- | :------------------ | :------------------
>       1 | 10.0.0.1   | 01/01/2017 00:00:00 | 01/02/2017 00:00:00
>       1 | 10.0.0.1   | 01/02/2017 00:00:00 | 01/03/2017 00:00:00
>       1 | 10.0.0.1   | 01/03/2017 00:00:00 | 01/03/2017 00:00:00
>       2 | 10.0.0.2   | 01/02/2017 00:00:00 | 01/02/2017 00:00:00
>       3 | 10.0.0.3   | 01/02/2017 00:00:00 | 01/02/2017 00:00:00
> ```

And then try to find the best match:

> ```
> WITH ipList as
> (
>     SELECT account, ip_address, created_date, 
>            COALESCE(LEAD(created_date) OVER (PARTITION BY account, ip_address ORDER BY created_date), created_date) next_date
>     FROM   Table1
> )
> SELECT    (SELECT TOP(1) ipList.account
>            FROM   ipList
>            WHERE  t2.ip_address = ipList.ip_address
>            AND    t2.created_date >= ipList.created_date 
>            AND    t2.created_date <=  ipList.next_date) account,
>           t2.ip_address, 
>           t2.created_date
> FROM      Table2 t2;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> account | ip_address | created_date       
> ------: | :--------- | :------------------
>       1 | 10.0.0.1   | 01/02/2017 00:00:00
>       2 | 10.0.0.2   | 01/02/2017 00:00:00
>       3 | 10.0.0.3   | 01/02/2017 00:00:00
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d22c338161b5b7882787d5112089bc88)*

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from ( SELECT t2.ip_address, t2.created_date, t1.account_id 
            , row_number() over (partition by t2.ip_address 
                                 order by abs(datediff(dd, t1.created_date, t2.created_date)) as dd
       FROM Table2 t2 
       join Table1 t1
       on t2.ip_address = t1.ip_address
     ) tt
where dd = 1
```